# ¿Cómo insertar filas a una matriz de numpy?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matrices, numpy

Tengo una matriz creada con numpy:

```
matriz = numpy.matrix([]);
```

Intento insertar filas en un bucle (algo parecido a):

```
for i in range(3) : matriz = numpy.insert(matriz, i, [i + 1, 0, 0])
```

Esperaba que el resultado fuera:

```
matrix([[1, 0, 0], [2, 0, 0], [3, 0, 0]])
```

Sin embargo obtengo:

```
matrix([[ 1.,  2.,  3.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])
```

¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eso ocurre porque no indicas el eje al que quieres añadir los datos (`0` para `filas` y `1` para `columnas`). Si este parámetro no se indica el array/matrix es **aplanado** primero como puedes ver en la documentación de [`numpy.insert()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.insert.html):

> axis : int, optional
>
> > Axis along which to insert values. If axis is None then arr is flattened first.

La sintaxis correcta sería:

```
matriz=numpy.insert(matriz, i, [i + 1, 0, 0], axis=0)
```

El problema es que estás tratando de añadir una fila con tres columnas a una matriz de 1x0. Eso lanza un error. La solución puede ser inicializar una matriz de 3 filas pero vacía. Para ello podemos usar `numpy.empty`:

```
import numpy

matriz =  numpy.matrix(numpy.empty(shape=(0,3), dtype=int))
for i in range(3):
    matriz=numpy.insert(matriz, i, [i + 1, 0, 0], axis = 0)
```

De todas formas hay formas más eficientes de hacer esto como:

```
import numpy

matriz = numpy.matrix([[i+1, 0, 0] for i in range(3)], dtype=int)
```

Especifico el tipo de dato con `dtype` porque de no hacerlo será `float` por defecto.

En ambos casos obtenemos:

```
matrix([[1, 0, 0],    
        [2, 0, 0],    
        [3, 0, 0]])
```

No obstante el primer método (usando `np.insert()`) es bastante más ineficiente que el segundo (list comprehensions), yo obtengo los siguientes resultados para añadir 100000 filas:

`np.insert()`: 9.337375402450562 segundos
`list comprehensions`: 0.07504963874816895 segundos

Comment: Creo que me voy a decantar por la segunda opción. Creo un array multidimensional, al cual le añado elementos (filas) y después hacer `numpy.matrix(array)`. Gracias por la respuesta.

Comment: @JoseHermosillaRodrigo He hecho unas pequeñas pruebas de rendimiento y es lo esperado, puedes mirar los resultados al final de la respuesta (la he editado), son bastante significativos. El problema de insert() es que se está constantemente haciendo copias en memoria del array lo cual repercute mucho en el rendimiento. Saludos.