# Agregar valores a una matriz vacía de numpy

Tags: python, array, numpy, raspberry-pi

Estoy utilizando `numpy` en Raspberry para crear una matriz de ceros, la que posteriormente quiero rellenar con los valores obtenidos con las lecturas de un sensor, pero estoy teniendo problemas, el código que estoy utilizando es el siguiente:

```
import numpy as np

matriz = np.zeros((5,5))
x = 0
y = 0

for x in range(5):
    for y in range (5):
        matriz[x,y] = temperatura1
```

Necesito que cada elemento de la matriz se vaya rellenando con una nueva lectura de mi sensor, cuyo valor se almacena en la variable `temperatura1`, el problema es que la matriz se rellena únicamente con un valor, el mismo valor en todas las casillas, al imprimirlo obtengo algo así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Quizas esto te pueda ayudar https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/39070/c%C3%B3mo-insertar-filas-a-una-matriz-de-numpy?rq=1

Comment: Fernando si entre cada iteración del ciclo no haces una nueva lectura del valor del sensor y  actualizas el valor de `temperatura1` lógicamente todos los ítems van a tener el mismo valor. Falta información para poder orientar mejor, por ejemplo ¿Cómo lees el valor?, ¿Cada cuanto tiempo lo haces o quieres registrarlo en la matriz?

Comment: el valor lo estoy leyendo de un sensor infrarrojo mlx90614 por protocolo i2c, esta dentro de un while infinito que se actualiza cada 0.5 segundos, cuando detecta una temperatura de objeto mayor a 10 grados centigrados a la ambiente, inicia el registro de temperaturas en la matriz,